# Run-time error 3134 "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax-error

I am for the first time posting question in this platform. Currently, I am running into a problem of executing my assignment of online shopping database. When I try to register an account into it, it always pops up a window say run-time 3134 error, syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. I was trying any possibilities in order to solve the problem but it won't work. So, any solution to counter this problem? Thanks for your many helping.

Here is my codes:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Login table (FirstName,LastName,Gender,UserName,Password,Email,Phone) VALUES ('" & Me.FirstName & "','" & Me.LastName & "','" & Me.Gender & "','" & Me.UserName & "', '" & 
Me.Password & "','" & Me.Email & "','" & Me.Phone & "')"
```

Comment: Maybe you need to escape the cell values? It's also safer to use an ORM library instead of running raw database queries.

Comment: Why do you have the word `table` in the statement? Is it supposed to be `Login_table`?

Comment: If object names have space or special character, must enclose in brackets (`[ ]`): `[Login table]`.Advise not to use either in naming convention.

Comment: A common convention is to use a prefix for object naming, like: tblLogin, qryLogin, frmLogin, rptLogin.

Comment: My best guess is still that the table is named `Login` and he thought he needed the word `table` as part of the syntax, but perhaps we will never know.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the table you're trying to `INSERT INTO` is named `Login Table`, you have a space in the table name, which means any time you reference that table you need to surround it in square brackets.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Login table]` (FirstName,LastName,Gender,UserName,Password,Email,Phone) VALUES ('" & Me.FirstName & "','" & Me.LastName & "','" & Me.Gender & "','" & Me.UserName & "', '" & 
Me.Password & "','" & Me.Email & "','" & Me.Phone & "')"
```

This is one of the main problems with naming your table with spaces. Also, `Login table` is an especially bad name - you already know it's a table, so why do you need to repeat that information in the table name? And if you insist on using table names that are more than one word, you should use an underscore rather tha a space (like `Login_table`) to reduce the work involved with every query and prevent problems like the one you're having here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a stored query that points to the form controls as parameters and avoid VBA variable concatenation and quote punctuation. Also, query design in Access GUI does not allow users to save query with syntax errors.

**SQL**

Adjust `myForm` to actual form name.

```sql
INSERT INTO [Login table] 
    (FirstName, 
     LastName, 
     Gender, 
     UserName,
     Password, 
     Email, 
     Phone) 
VALUES 
    (Forms!myForm!FirstName,
     Forms!myForm!LastName,
     Forms!myForm!Gender,
     Forms!myForm!UserName, 
     Forms!myForm!Password,
     Forms!myForm!Email,
     Forms!myForm!Phone)
```

**VBA**

No need to close action queries and add `SetWarnings` to avoid update prompts.

```vb
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedAppendQuery"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Answer (score 0):

`Password` is a reserved word, so:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Login table] (FirstName,LastName,Gender,UserName,[Password],Email,Phone) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found that the the table had a field that was using a reserved name Note. By placing it in `` quotes (`Note`) fixed the issue.